# Increase Logo Size In Invoice

Tags: magento-1.7, sales

Default logo dimensions for invoice is 200*50.If I upload image with dimensions 216*100.How to set size in the code.So far,I've tried changing

```
protected function insertLogo(&$page, $store = null)
    {
        $image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/logo', $store);
        if ($image) {
            $image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
            if (is_file($image)) {
                $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($image);
                $page->drawImage($image, 25, 820, 125, 900);
            }
        }
        //return $page;
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which Magento version is this? Did you overwrite entire method or  you have extended it in another class?

Comment: Version 1.6.For now,I'm overwriting existing method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the content box arguments to be [25, 775, 133, 825].

Used units seem to be double the pixels and the vertical dimension starts at the bottom of the page. Enough to spend hours trying to make small changes to PDF print-outs.

Also, you'll have to push the rest of the page down a bit as the new image is a bit taller.

The whole `insertLogo()` function would look something like this:

```
protected function insertLogo(&$page, $store = null)
{
    $image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/logo', $store);
    if ($image) {
        $image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
        if (is_file($image)) {
            $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($image);
            $page->drawImage($image, 25, 775, 133, 825);
            $this->y = 760;
        }
    }
    //return $page;
}
```

That said, you may want to consider back porting the function from Magento 1.7, where this all is automatically calculated from dimensions of the actual image.